# The output of dscl . -list /Users includes a user called /. What is that mystery user?

Tags: macos, user-account

I was playing with `dscl` and noticed that when I list all the users using `dscl . -list /Users` the first user in the list is `/`. Just the single / followed by nothing else.

All the other users show up as you'd normally expect with root, nobody and so on. I've tried probing it with `dscl . -read /Users/` but it just gives me `name: dsRecTypeStandard:Users`. I think because it is just a slash the command won't take the `/` as a name and instead just acts like I called it on `/Users`.

Anyone seen this mystery `/` user before? Any ideas where it came from?

I'm running 1.14 Mojave. This computer originally had 1.12 Sierra and was upgraded to 1.13 than 1.14 as they came out. Can't say when this user appeared.